# Does LinearLayout have a max height?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical linearlayout that won't stretch beyond a certain limit.

This is the layout with centerCrop in the imageview
http://tinypic.com/r/20nm6s/5

This is the layout with no crop set (so it should be full width and huge)
http://tinypic.com/r/vzk7kw/5

So my thought is that there is some implicit max height that I'm not seeing in my layout but I can't see where it is, can you spot my error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/dropshadow"
            >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/heading"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/featuredimage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="1000dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is no point using the LinearLayout in your posted code. You can be able to achieve it using Relative Layout.

Comment: what are the actual pixel dimensions of the image?  Can you post the code that loads and sets the image?

Comment: I'have found a solution to provide `maxHeight` to `ScrollView`. That solution can also be used for any type of view. Please read more at http://chintanrathod.com/maxheightscrollview-in-android-using-android-studio/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "implicit" max height of the layout is the height of its parent. Since you're using `wrap_content` on both layouts, that means the parent is *effectively* the screen area, minus whatever other views you're using (such as the `TextView`). Unless you place it in a scrolling container, such as a `ScrollView`, it won't ever exceed the size of the screen.

The reason your `ImageView` isn't showing up "full width and huge" when you remove the crop is because the default `scaleType` for an `ImageView` is `fitCenter`. This particular view is bounded by the layout's **width**, so it shrinks the image while maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: Also, the LinearLayout being in the RelativeLayout for what you have is wasteful. Place the XMLNS tag on the LinearLayout and remove the RelativeLayout.

Comment: You could also remove the Linear and use Relative with appropriate attributes, but Linear would be simpler. Either way, you *definitely* don't need both of them.